# Trying to Find the Solutions to Exercise 2 Chapter 17 in Sams Teach Yourself SQL in 24 Hours 5th Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Unfortunately, the 5th edition of Sams Teach Yourself SQL in 24 Hours is riddled with errors, but I like the format and method in which the book uses to teach you SQL from scratch.  I was able to fix the errors on my own, having previous experience, but I have reached a wall in Chapter 17 for exercise 2.

The book provided incorrect solutions to the problems.  I assumed it was just poor formatting (forgetting a parenthesis or something minor like that), so I played around with the formatting of the solutions until the query would go through.  Alas, no success!

I'm using Microsoft SQL.

Here are the problems and the solutions the book provided for exercise 2:

2. Add another table called EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL that contains a large amount of pay history data. Use the table that follows to write the series of SQL statements to address the following problems.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL
(PAYHIST_ID      VARCHAR(9)       NOT NULL primary key,
EMP_ID           VARCHAR(9)       NOT NULL,
START_DATE       DATETIME         NOT NULL,
END_DATE         DATETIME,
PAY_RATE         DECIMAL(4,2)     NOT NULL,
SALARY           DECIMAL(8,2)     NOT NULL,
BONUS            DECIMAL(8,2)     NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT EMP_FK FOREIGN KEY (EMP_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_TBL (EMP_ID));
```

I then inserted random values with existing employees in the database.

a. Find the SUM of the salaried versus nonsalaried employees by the year in which their pay started.

**Their Solution**

```
SELECT START_YEAR,
       SUM(SALARIED) AS SALARIED,
       SUM(HOURLY) AS HOURLY 
FROM (SELECT YEAR(E.START_DATE) AS START_YEAR,
             COUNT(E.EMP_ID) AS SALARIED,
             0 AS HOURLY
      FROM EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL E 
      INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(START_DATE) START_DATE,
                          EMP_ID
                  FROM EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL
                  GROUP BY EMP_ID) F
      ON E.EMP_ID = F.EMP_ID
      AND E.START_DATE = F.START_DATE
      WHERE E.SALARY > 0.00 
      GROUP BY YEAR(E.START_DATE)
      UNION
      SELECT YEAR(E.START_DATE) AS START_YEAR,
             0 AS SALARIED, 
             COUNT(E.EMP_ID) AS HOURLY
      FROM EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL E 
      INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(START_DATE) START_DATE,
                         EMP_ID
                  FROM EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL
                  GROUP BY EMP_ID) F 
      ON E.EMP_ID = F.EMP_ID
      AND E.START_DATE = F.START_DATE
      WHERE E.PAY_RATE > 0.00
      GROUP BY YEAR(E.START_DATE)) A
GROUP BY START_YEAR
ORDER BY START_YEAR;
```

I've tried the code, tried to fix it myself, but no avail.  Looking at this coding only confused me more on coming up with a solution myself.  I do understand that they want columns called Start_Year, Salaried, and Hourly; that can be understood from the question and their own coding.

After going through this nightmare, I don't even want to try to see if their solutions for the others problems will work.  I took a peek at the other solutions and they seem to have the same, problematic formatting.

b. Find the difference in the yearly pay of salaried employees versus nonsalaried employees by the year in which their pay started. Consider the nonsalaried employees to be working full time during the year ( PAY_RATE * 52 * 40).

**Their Solution**

```
SELECT START_YEAR,
       SALARIED AS SALARIED,
       HOURLY AS HOURLY,
       (SALARIED - HOURLY) AS PAY_DIFFERENCE
FROM (SELECT YEAR(E.START_DATE) AS START_YEAR,
             AVG(E.SALARY) AS SALARIED,
             0 AS HOURLY
      FROM EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL E
      INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(START_DATE) START_DATE,
                         EMP_ID
                  FROM EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL 
                  GROUP BY EMP_ID) F
      ON E.EMP_ID = F.EMP_ID
      AND E.START_DATE = F.START_DATE
      WHERE E.SALARY > 0.00
      GROUP BY YEAR(E.START_DATE)
      UNION
      SELECT YEAR(E.START_DATE) AS START_YEAR,
             0 AS SALARIED,
             AVG(E.PAY_RATE * 52 * 40 ) AS HOURLY
      FROM EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL E 
      INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(START_DATE) START_DATE,
                          EMP_ID
                  FROM EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL 
                  GROUP BY EMP_ID) F 
      ON E.EMP_ID = F.EMP_ID 
      AND E.START_DATE = F.START_DATE 
      WHERE E.PAY_RATE > 0.00 
      GROUP BY YEAR(E.START_DATE)) A 
GROUP BY START_YEAR 
ORDER BY START_YEAR;
```

c. Find the difference in what employees make now versus what they made when they started with the company. Again, consider the nonsalaried employees to be full-time. Also consider that the employees’ current pay is reflected in the EMPLOYEE_PAY_TBL as well as the EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL . In the pay history table, the current pay is reflected as a row with the END_DATE for pay equal to NULL.

**Their Solution**

```
SELECT CURRENTPAY.EMP_ID,
       STARTING_ANNUAL_PAY,
       CURRENT_ ANNUAL_PAY,
       CURRENT_ANNUAL_PAY - STARTING_ANNUAL_PAY AS PAY_DIFFERENCE
FROM (SELECT EMP_ID,(SALARY + (PAY_RATE * 52 * 40)) AS CURRENT_ANNUAL_PAY
      FROM EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL
      WHERE END_DATE IS NULL) CURRENTPAY
INNER JOIN
(SELECT E.EMP_ID,
        (SALARY + (PAY_RATE * 52 * 40)) AS STARTING_ANNUAL_PAY
 FROM EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL E
      (SELECT MIN(START_DATE) START_DATE,
              EMP_ID
       FROM EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL
       GROUP BY EMP_ID) F
       ON E.EMP_ID = F.EMP_ID
       AND E.START_DATE = F.START_DATE) STARTINGPAY
 ON CURRENTPAY.EMP_ID = STARTINGPAY.EMP_ID;
```

I was fine with the errors in this book, easily able to fix them...  But this problem is making me want to rage at the authors for leaving so many errors!

Edit:

I would really like help in solving these problems.  As an added note, the solutions don't need to follow what they provided; it can be a new way of approaching the solution.  I just need help understanding how I can approach the solution.

Edit:

I want to apologize!  The coding works now for some reason and I believe it has to do with the database now registering the EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL.  I had issues yesterday where the database acted like the table didn't exist (it had it underlined in red and said it didn't exist and I most definitely checked the spelling), but I was able to do simple queries on it despite the issue.  I guess a complicated query caused it to fuss more.  It was saying that fields that I clearly did have in the table did not exist.

It's now registering the EMPLOYEE_PAYHIST_TBL and its columns, after I started up my computer today, and allowed the queries for every problem to go through...  Very unusual...

I'm sorry for not stating this, I was going with the idea that it's purely syntax errors before, but it was issues with the database afterall.

What could have caused the database to not register the table before?  Cache issues?

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: The errors I was getting was that columns in the table did not exist, despite them clearly existing.  It was also acting like the table did not exist, having it underlined in red, despite it existing and I even copy and pasted its name from the Object Explorer to the query to make sure it's not the spelling.  Other than that, it was giving a lot of syntax errors.  I was able to do simple queries on the table, despite the database complaining on it's existence, so I assumed it could do complicated queries.  Since it's registering the table today, the queries now have no issues.  My apologies!

Comment: I don't understand why it wasn't registering the table before though.  Sorry again!  Thanks for replying to this post however!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.